# Keep Colorbox always centered on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, colorbox

When using thickbox if a user scrolled vertically the thickbox would always stay centered. However with colorbox if they scroll they lose site of the colorbox and just see a grayed out background. How can I update colorbox to have the same functionality where it maintains position on the screen regardless of user scrolling.

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html
http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

resize your window to have a vertical scrollbar and scroll and you can see the difference.

Thanks

Comment: The response below worked but the colorbox was always anchored top left. Anyone know how to get it to be centered on the page and not move then the browser scrolls?

Comment: You still need an answer to this? I'm taking bets there was something from completing the color-box from initializing properly, it's build into it to keep it centered unless you specify specifically not to.

Answer (score 16):

I may be a bit late, but FYI you can simply use the "fixed" option in your colorbox declaration. This option is "false" by default. If you set it to "true" you get the result you want:

```
$('#my_box').colorbox({
    fixed: true
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that thickbox uses the css position:fixed to align the box, whereas colorbox uses a relative position. In the colorbox.css file try changing the line "#colorbox{}" to "#colorbox{position:fixed}" I tested it in Firebug and that seems to fix it.

The position fixed CSS won't work in IE6.

Comment: Thanks..that did work. Not concerned about IE6. Any idea how to make it centered in the middle? Right now it's always top left.

Comment: #colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}